# Sufficient condition to check whether a group is Noetherian

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups

Suppose $G$ is a finitely generated group. What conditions on $G$(or some subgroups of $G$) will force it to be a Noetherian group?

Of course, if all subgroups are finitely generated or ACC on subgroups is satisfied, then we are done by definition. Are there any known results which can help prove neotherianity of group $G$, if $G$ was known to be finitely generated?

Comment: A word that come to my mind when I hear Noetherian is ACC (Ascending Chain Condition). I guess [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_series#Noetherian_groups.2C_Artinian_groups) will have what you are looking for!

Comment: I consider the  condition ACC and every subgroup is finitely generated as definition basically, so I am looking for something else than this.

Answer (score 2):

For a solvable group being Noetherian is equivalent with being polycyclic.
Similarly, a finitely generated nilpotent group is Noetherian. You also have the "standard subgroup-quotient-extension-closeness", i.e. subgroups of Noetherian groups are Noetherian, quotients of Noetherian groups are Noetherian and if a normal subgroup and the corresponding quotient is Noetherian then so is the group. If the the group ring $R[G]$ is noetherian (in the sense of rings) for some non-zero commutative ring $R$ then $G$ is Noetherian. Moreover Noetherian groups need to be Hopfian (necessary condition) and it is (to my knowledge) open if "being Noetherian" is a quasi-isometric invariant of finitely presented groups.

Comment: Something like this is what I am looking for. I will wait till tomorrow in case someone has something more to say, I will accept the answer tomorrow. Thanks for this answer.